# AS3 OOP. How do I make an object move across a game board depending on the value of the dice?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, dice

I am creating a board game and I am using Object Oriented Programming with AS3.  I created a movie clip with a circle that moves across the game board.  There are 18 squares and 18 frames.  I have a button that gives you a value with a dice with the random number function:

```
public function rollDie():void
    {_dieValue = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6)
        this.gotoAndStop(_dieValue);}
```

I have a class for the dice button, die, gameboard, and the main board.  I am trying to make the circle move across the board(or go to the frame in the mc) depending on what the value I get with the dice.  Here is my code so far:

Main Board:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class DiceOut extends MovieClip
{
           public function DiceOut()
       {
                   trace("class diceout defined");
        createListeners();
    }

    public function createListeners():void
    {
        //trace("createListeners");
        rollButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
    }

    public function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        die1.rollDie();
        trace(die1.dieValue);
    }}}
```

Dice class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class die extends MovieClip {

    private var _dieValue:uint;

    public function die() {
        trace("dice created");
        stop();
    }
    public function rollDie():void
    {
        _dieValue = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6)
        this.gotoAndStop(_dieValue);
    }
    public function get dieValue():uint
    {
        return _dieValue;
    }}}
```

Gameboard class:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class gameboard extends MovieClip {
    public function gameboard() {
        trace("Gameboard Created");
        stop();}}}
```

DiceButton class:

```
package  {  
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
public class GameButton extends MovieClip {
    public function GameButton() {
        trace("Button created");
        stop(); 
        createListeners();
    }
    private function createListeners():void
    {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverOver);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hoverOff);
    }
    public function hoverOver(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
    public function hoverOff(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
    }}}
```

If anyone could please give some insight that would be very helpful.  The mc instance for the gameboard is gameBoard.

Also, if anyone knows how to trigger a labeled frame depending on which square the circle lands on that would be a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an action to happen depending on the result of another action in another Object, you can first use Event Dispatching to communicate between Objects and send relevant values from one to another.

```
//In the Die class
public function rollDie():void
{
    _dieValue = Math.ceil(Math.random()*6)
    this.gotoAndStop(_dieValue);

    //assuming that all your Objects have the same parent, 
    //namely the main stage
    //also, you would have to create a CustomEvent class...
    parent.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent(_dieValue ) );
}

//In your Circle class you must listen to the CustomEvent
//you can do that after the Circle has been added to the stage
//check the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
private function addedToStage( event:Event ):void
{
     //remove the event listener
     //listen to your CustomEvent
     parent.addEventListener( CustomEvent.DICE_ROLLED , diceRolled );
}

private function diceRolled( event: CustomEvent ):void
{
     var dieValue:int = event.dieValue;

     // now that you have the value in the Circle class
     // you can react accordingly

     //here I use a switch statement but there are other
     //options of course...
     switch( dieValue )
     {
             case 1:
                //go to this square...
                break;

             case 2:
                //go to this other square...
                break;

             etc...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, what do you mean by frame? an actual animation frame, or a frame around a square?
If I understand your code correctly, you could create an `Array` of `Point` objects and have these all correspond to positions on the board. then just add the die value to the index each time.

Main board class:

```
protected var playerIndex:Number = 0;

public function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    die1.rollDie();

    playerIndex += die1.dieValue;// This will move the player forward the number on the die
}

// add this to the createListeners method:
    playerCircle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, PlayerEnt);

public function PlayerEnt (e:Event) {
    // this retrieves the position of the square that the player is on
    playerCircle.x = gameBoard.boardPositions[playerIndex].x;
    playerCircle.y = gameBoard.boardPositions[playerIndex].y;
}
```

gameBoard class:

```
private var boardPositions:Array;

public function gameboard() {
    trace("Gameboard Created");
    stop();

    boardPositions = new Array(//Insert positions here, there are lots of ways of making this information so I won't go into them
}
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't help you, but your question is a bit unclear. I suggest that you try to give more of a description, for example what do you meann by frames? Are you using animation to move the player?